# get_permalink() of page the enclosing page not posts

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, loop, templates, custom-post-type-archives

I have spent the last hour googling and trying different methods but nothing works the way I want it to.

Within the loop of the posts, I need to get the permalink of the main page.

### Example

You have a portfolio custom post type and then a page where you show all of your work `archive-portfolio.php`, I need to get the link to the main portfolio page/archive-page within the loop.

The latest I have tried is getting the ID of the page outside of the loop and setting it to a variable then calling it later on in the loop.

```
$page_id = get_the_ID();
```

but because i am using an `archive-{post-type}.php` it is not working, correctly.

Is there another solution other than changing over to `page-{template`} and implementing that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the `get_post_type_archive_link` function. It requires a post type as a parameter, but since you're already on the archive page you should be able to use it in combination with `get_post_type`, which gets the current post type by default:

```
$permalink = get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type() );
```

See more on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$obj = get_queried_object();
$link = get_term_link($obj);
```

Now you can use it as you want.